# USB port to detect "close" or "open" switch

Tags: usb, switch-statement, alarm

I need to make a program that would play a sound as I press a push button switch. My idea is to use the USB port, and that if I short 2 wires from it (like for example the data+ and data-), the program would play a sound repeatedly while the 2 wires are shorted. Is my idea possible and simple to do? Can you please help me do it using VB? Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not practical.  USB ports do not have that feature is far as I know.  There are plenty of small, cheap USB microcontroller boards that are up to the task though.

For example, you could get an [A-Star 32U4 Micro](http://www.pololu.com/product/3101), program it using the Arduino IDE, and make it send a certain message on the its virtual COM port (which is accessed from the `Serial` object) when a button is pressed and another message when it is released.  Then in Visual Basc, you would use the [SerialPort class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) to connect to the A-Star's COM port and listen for that message.

Answer (score 0):

USB ports are mainly used for transmitter and receiver communications for data transfers. They are not used for open or closed switch detection. In order to use a USB port for switch detection, you can used a serial to USB conversion breakout board with a specialized IC chip designed to detect an open or closed switch and communicate this via the USB protocols to send out a communications data transmission that a switch has just been open or closed. Then you would program an application in any language to listen on that USB port for this specific data transmission for a closed or open thrown switch. You can potentially detect about 4 switches opened or closed simultaneously if you want. And this serial to USB breakout board can easily be purchased online at:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/199